# ¿Cómo eliminar un archivo y que no se produzca ninguna excepción si el archivo no existe?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo eliminar un archivo en C#? \documento.txt, y si el archivo no existe no se me no se produce ninguna excepción ejemplos

```
if exist "C:\documento.txt"

delete "C:\documento.txt"

else

return nothing (ignore
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Mira la clase File, ahi tenes los metodos necesarios

Answer (score 1):

Deberás utilizar la clase File para ello

```
using System.IO;
```

Después puedes borrar el archivo mediante el siguiente método:

```
  string fileName = "C:\documento.txt";

         if (File.Exists(fileName)) // si existe el archivo
           {
             File.Delete(fileName); //borras el archivo
           }
```

De este modo si existe el archivo lo borra, si no existe no realiza ninguna función.